# Select and DISCARD by COLUMN

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I was trying to make a **difficult** query with these tables:

**service**:

```
id_service             description                  cost
    1                  service 1                     20
    2                  service 2                     30
    3                  service 3                     25
```

**history**:

```
id_history               status              id_service    
    1                      0                     1
    2                      1                     1
    3                      2                     1
    4                      3                     1
    5                      0                     2
    6                      4                     1
    7                      1                     2
    8                      2                     2
    9                      0                     3
   10                      1                     3
   11                      3                     2
```

I need to know, which services are not complete (status != 4) and group by the recent update. Maybe, like this:

```
id_history              status            id_service          description
    11                    3                   2                service 2
    8                     2                   2                service 2
    7                     1                   2                service 2
    5                     0                   2                service 2
    10                    1                   3                service 3
    9                     0                   3                service 3
```

This is my current query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.descripcion
FROM history a 
   JOIN service b ON a.id_service = b.id_service
WHERE a.status != 4

GROUP BY a.id_service    

ORDER BY a.id_history DESC
```

Which just returns one row per `id_service`:

```
ID_HISTORY  STATUS  ID_SERVICE  DESCRIPTION
    9         0         3       service 3
    5         0         2       service 2
    1         0         1       service 1
```

Comment: i think you want to `ORDER BY a.id_service, a.id_history DESC` and get rid of `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `not exists` to eliminate the service with status 4

```
select h.id_history, h.status, h.id_service, s.description
from 
service s
join history h
on h.id_service = s.id_service
where not exists ( select 1 from history h2
                   where h.id_service = h2.id_service
                   and h2.status = 4
                 )
order by h.id_history desc, h.id_service desc
```

if you want the latest status for each service then you can use `group by` in the subquery

```
select h.id_history, h.status, h.id_service, s.description
from 
service s
join (
select max(status) as status, id_service
from history
group by id_service
)t
on s.id_service =t.id_service
and t.status  !=4
join history h
on h.status = t.status
and h.id_service = t.id_service
order by h.id_history desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you mustn't use "Group by" something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.descripcion
FROM history a 
   JOIN service b ON a.id_service = b.id_service
WHERE a.status != 4
ORDER BY a.id_history DESC
```